# AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope

Tags: c, stack, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-case-permutation/

```
void dfs(char *subString, int currentIndex, char *S, char **res, int *returnSize){
    if (currentIndex==strlen(S)){
        subString[currentIndex] = '\0';
        res[*returnSize] = (char *) calloc(strlen(S)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(res[*returnSize], subString);
        (*returnSize)++;
        return;
    }

    char *ptr;
    if isalpha(S[currentIndex]){
        char tem[3] = {toupper(S[currentIndex]), tolower(S[currentIndex]), '\0'};
        ptr = tem;
    }
    else{
        char tem[2] = {S[currentIndex], '\0'};
        ptr = tem;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<strlen(ptr); j++){
        subString[currentIndex] = *(ptr+j);
        dfs(subString, currentIndex+1, S, res, returnSize);
    }
}

char ** letterCasePermutation(char *S, int *returnSize){
    char **res = (char **) calloc(4096, sizeof(char *));
    char tmp[strlen(S)+1];
    *returnSize = 0;
    dfs(tmp, 0, S, res, returnSize);
    return res;
}
```

there is no error through my local test using `valgrind`. When tested online, it reports

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffe1dcb74b0 at pc 0x7f3fdc5d59bd bp 0x7ffe1dcb7410 sp 0x7ffe1dcb6bb8
READ of size 3 at 0x7ffe1dcb74b0 thread T0
    #0 0x7f3fdc5d59bc  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x669bc)
    #4 0x7f3fdb65f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Address 0x7ffe1dcb74b0 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 96 in frame
  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 34) 'tem'
    [96, 99) 'tem' <== Memory access at offset 96 is inside this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x669bc) 
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x100043b8ee40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8ee50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8ee60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8ee70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8ee80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 02 f2
=>0x100043b8ee90: f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2[f8]f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8eea0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ca ca ca ca 05 cb cb cb
  0x100043b8eeb0: cb cb cb cb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100043b8eec0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 04 f2 f2 f2
  0x100043b8eed0: f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2
  0x100043b8eee0: f2 f2 f2 f2 04 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

---

With the inspiration from @kaylum, I finally made this solution right.

```
void dfs(char *subString, int currentIndex, char *S, char **res, int *returnSize){
    ...

    char ptr[3];
    if isalpha(S[currentIndex]){
        char tem[3] = {toupper(S[currentIndex]), tolower(S[currentIndex]), '\0'};
        strcpy(ptr, tem);
    }
    else{
        char tem[2] = {S[currentIndex], '\0'};
        strcpy(ptr, tem);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<strlen(ptr); j++){
        subString[currentIndex] = *(ptr+j);
        dfs(subString, currentIndex+1, S, res, returnSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char tem[3]` that variable only exists inside the `if` block. Storing a pointer to it and then using it outside that block results in Undefined Behaviour. That's what `valgrind` is telling you.

Comment: @kaylum that makes sense. thanks.

Comment: @kaylum Why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in the comments and is needlessly open. Answering it on behalf of the commenter.

> char tem[3] that variable only exists inside the if block. Storing a
> pointer to it and then using it outside that block results in
> Undefined Behaviour. That's what valgrind is telling you. –  kaylum